# How do I access JSON elements through javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

The JSON file I have is following:

```
{
  "root": {
    "Quizsize": null,
    "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}page": [
      {
        "@xid": "page1623",
        "@title": "Quiz Landing Page",
        "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}comment": null,
        "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}skills": null,
        "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}info": {
          "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/common}property": {
            "@name": "quiz_landing",
            "@value": "true"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
}
```

I am loading this JSON file using :

```
var jsondata = eval("("+chapterRequest.responseText+")") ;
Root = jsondata.root
```

Now I want to access @xid which is "page1623 and @name which is "quiz_landing". I dont know how to do this,Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'access'? If you want to read property value, you have to loop through them, if you want a containing node, you have to loop through properties also and look for a matching value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON.parse(x) is better than eval(x), for one. It is not supported natively by some browsers though. If you want to access @xid, "urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}page" points to an array whose first element is an object.

So use **Root["{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}page"][0]["@xid"]**. Or mix bracket and dot notation. Your choice, really.

Comment: Now the Error is: jsondata.root is undefined, its not able to access the root property.

Comment: Its working now,the problem was I was using some other JSON file that doesnot has root property..Thanks Steve

Comment: @Steve Wang: THX for ur answer "JSON.parse(x) is better than eval(x)"

Answer (score 1):

When the key isn't a valid identifier, you use `object['key']` instead of `object.key`, so `jsondata.root['{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}page'][0]['@xid']`.